# Geometry Nodes and Duplicating Premade/Procedural Geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make a procedural building from scratch despite being a bit of a rookie. I have a messy node set up where I have a value node that does math to calculate the correct amount of "wall" pieces that are transformed and scaled how I want them. My issue is that I am trying to essentially duplicate the geometry I have made in the node editor vertically. I want to be able to procedurally adjust the amount of layers on the building.

So far I have just used a regular transform node to duplicate the wall sections. I could duplicate it with this same method once, but not with a slider as I can't get the geometry to fit into something like a Point Instance node.

Is there a way to "duplicate" or create multiple versions of the geometry node? My thoughts are that I could make a straight line in a separate mesh then use geo to duplicate it. However, I wouldn't have all the sliders under one roof, and the math nodes would be difficult to translate over. Otherwise I'm at a loss. Point Instance only allows you to use an existing mesh.

[image: Node Tree]

[image: Result]

As requested here is a bit of annotation behind my (likely very flawed) thought process.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do. If i understood you you want this:

Just create two objects with geometry nodes. One creates your x-y "floor" and the other one "copies" this to the z axis.

node setup for x-y-floor:

[image]

result:

[image]

node setup for z-axis:

[image]

result:

[image]

video demo: https://youtu.be/OGp9FQv1TSM